# when javascript function alter html input text ,I want the input text trigger a event like calling other JS function

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I try to use onchange but it just work when you alter the text by focusing the mouse cursor on it , but when alter the text by using function its not do anything

```
        <input type="button" value="TestButton" onclick="AlterText()" />
    <br />
    <input id="txtbox1" type="text" onchange="AlertMe()"  />

    <script>
    var counter = 0;
    function AlterText(){
        counter=counter +1;
        document.getElementById('txtbox1').value = counter;
    }
    function AlertMe(){
    alert("Done!..");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why dont you call it yourselves `AlertMe.call(this);` after changing the value.

Comment: You can call `document.getElementById('txtbox1').onchange()` function if `document.getElementById('txtbox1').onchange` is not undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call it yourself.

```
var counter = 0;
function AlterText(){
    counter=counter +1;
    document.getElementById('txtbox1').value = counter;
    AlertMe.call(document.getElementById('txtbox1'));
}
function AlertMe(){
alert("Done!..");
}
```

Comment: I want the event occurs from the html events , the function that alter the textbox black boxing , so I just need to know how to detect the changed .

Comment: I am not getting what you are trying to say.

Comment: It's like when using ajax calender on textbox so when the date changed inside the textbox , the  textbox trigger a event , do you know what i mean?

Comment: Your event will be triggered as you have registered it as event handler, also when you are changing it programmatically we are calling the function to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Input onchange doesn't fire for programattic changes, you need to fire it yourself with

```
document.getElementById('txtbox1').onchange();
```